# Is removing the last link to a memory mapped file safe

Tags: c, posix, mmap, unlink

Sometimes I use the following code piece to read files (error checking code omitted):

```
db = open(db_path, O_RDONLY);
fstat(db, info);
buffer = mmap(0, info->st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, db, 0);
close(db);
```

Note that I'm closing the file after the call to mmap. Then once I'm done with `buffer`:

```
munmap(buffer, info->st_size);
```

What will happen if somebody deletes the last hard link to the file from the filesystem (e.g. `unlink(db_path)`) and no process has a file descriptor to the file? Will this cause undefined behavior or is the operating system keeping the file until it is unmapped? I couldn't find documentation that explicitly states one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the official POSIX reference on `mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html)

> The `mmap()` function shall add an extra reference to the file associated with the file descriptor fildes which is not removed by a subsequent `close()` on that file descriptor. This reference shall be removed when there are no more mappings to the file.

So it's safe to use the mapped file until the `munmap` call.